# How to display http response [HTML] in windows without using web browser class

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I want to  display the html of webpages without using webBrowser class in C#.I don't know how to display the http response in windows form

Comment: Any specific reason for not using webBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider an open source library, *"HTML Renderer"* for displaying HTML contents on your winforms. Its available at Codeplex.

http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/

BTW any specific reason for not using webBrowser?